# windows XP doesn't go up after unubtu installation,

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, windows-xp

I must first admit that I'm pretty new to this whole "Linux" environment, so give me some slacks. :)
I'm using win XP, with Acronis true image.
After I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 version, the Linux is up and running.
When I power up my PC (Desktop). I receive a list of options to choose, and two of them are Acronis and Windows.
When I press Windows I get a nearly blank page, with only a mark blinking on the upper left side of the display, and there it's stuck.
When I press on Acronis, I get a notification that states :" Non system disk, press any key" and then it returns to the main list.

What do you think? Is there a way to fix it? how?
10x a lot in advanced,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like NTLDR is somehow messed up. Perhaps you could try using Ubuntu to download/burn Hiren's Boot CD, and boot from it. From there, see what happens when you use the "NTLDR" is missing option from the boot screen.